# Why my APK is working just in Samsung phone?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app, i Record an Audio and save in  NEW folder,
I also have an ArrayList to show the audios.
My app is just working in Samsung phone, when I try in nexus it gives me an error.
Here is my array list.

```
    public class FetchSongs {

        boolean fetchstatus=false;
        ArrayList<File> songs=new ArrayList<File>();

        String sep = File.separator; // Use this instead of hardcoding the "/"
        String newFolder = "FolderName";
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);

        FetchSongs(){

        }
        public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root){

            ArrayList<File> al=new ArrayList<File>();
            //File[] files=root.listFiles();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), newFolder);
            File[] files = file.listFiles();


            for (File singleFile : files){
                if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
                    al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));

                }
                else {
                    if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){
                        al.add(singleFile);
                    }
                }
            }

            fetchstatus=true;
            songs=al;
            return al;

        }
        public boolean getfetchstatus(){
            return fetchstatus;
        }
        public ArrayList<File> getsonglist(){
            return songs;
        }

    }
```

Here is my MainAct

```
             String sep = File.separator; // Use this instead of hardcoding the "/"
    String newFolder = "FolderName";
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);
    myNewFolder.mkdir();


    while (fs.getfetchstatus() != true) {
        mySongs = fs.findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());


    }
    if (mySongs != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    mySongs = fs.getsonglist();

    items = new String[mySongs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".3gp", "");

    }
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adp);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos", i);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

And here is the error when I test in Nexus phone

```
     org.usr.usr.mmusicplayer, PID: 1586                                                                 
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.usr.usr.mmusicplayer/org.usr.usr.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                          at org.usr.usr.musicplayer.FetchSongs.findSongs(FetchSongs.java:39)
                                                                          at org.usr.usr.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Does there exists the Directory 'FolderName' in the external storage of the Nexus phone?

Comment: can you check the folders  File[] files = file.listFiles();  what u get as in files if folder is empty may be it cause to nullpointer

Comment: the APK create the "FolderName" in samsung @Jj

Comment: It would be useful to indicate which line of code corresponds to the crash at FetchSongs.findSongs(FetchSongs.java:39)

Comment: @Pavan, yes when I open the app, it created the folder, so it is empty. in my samsung i open it, and it doesn't show anything in the ArrayList, but if I record an audio, it update normaly

Comment: Can I create this New external Folder in Nexus like is being created in Samsung?

Comment: i think  myNewFolder.mkdir(); will not work on some device can you try with  myNewFolder.mkdirs();

Comment: myNewFolder.mkdirs(), also didn't worked   :( @Pavan

Comment: Can you debug app and check that function that what file list you getting

Comment: Also check that if device is marshmallow and above then you have to handle permission for storage to create folder and acces it

Comment: @Pavan there is no error when i debug the app

Comment: and what abou storage permission

Comment: yes i put it in manifest @Pavan

Comment: if device os version is marshmallow and above you have to handle run time permission because it set to off by default  check this  for more info https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html